# res.send() Not Working When Inside of a Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm using express and attempting a simple GET querying my database. The client never receives the string from the server if it is being sent from the callback; meaning, the following code never sends the string back:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    ul.readTable(req.query.q, (stringToReturn) => {
        res.send(stringToReturn);
    })
}
```

The part that is particularly confusing to me is that if I put the res.send() outside of the callback, and send some dummy string, it successfully sends. So this code does manage to send a string:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    ul.readTable(req.query.q, (stringToReturn) => {
    })
    res.send("dummy string");
}
```

Obviously this isn't much use since it can't hold the data I want to send back, but it does mean there shouldn't be any other discrepancies. I have tried sending back a dummy string from the callback, but this also failed to send. I would think this would mean the issue would be from the fact that the res.send() is in the callback, but I've seen plenty of examples of others sending the data back in the callback.

Comment: try adding `return res.send("dummy string");`

Comment: I added that into the callback and am still having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that your callback is appropriately firing?
Your code looks alright in the current context which would lead me to believe that something is wrong with the callback not being invoked.

Comment: I have put console.log() into the callback and it seems to print out everything fine, it is also returning with the expected information.

Edit: it now appears as though the callback is not firing appropriately, though for an unrelated issue. Thank you

Comment: What is `res.send()` sending? Is it throwing any kind of an error, or are you getting `undefined`, or not sending anything at all?

Comment: It simply was not sending, though I believe Bryce to be correct that it was an issue with the callback, itself.